# Exif metadata does not give orientation for Google drive images

Tags: android, image, orientation, picasso, exif

I am working with displaying gallery/drive images in my app using **Picasso** library.
**Samsung** device captures all images in landscape mode, so that it added 90 degree rotation for portrait images. 
These images are displayed properly in Gallery but landscape in my app.

```
// Let's say photoUri is uri of google drive image
// i.e. photoUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D3%3Bdoc%3D3223"
// photoUri.getPath = "/document/acc=3;doc=3209"

ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

But `rotation` value is always 0.

I am facing the same issue even for image picked up from Google Photos app.
In that case I am getting

```
For image from Google Photos app,
photoUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F327/ORIGINAL/NONE/1460204671"
photoUri.getPath() = "/-1/1/content://media/external/file/327/ORIGINAL/NONE/1460204671"
```

My question is how to identify orientation for image uploaded in Google drive or while picking from Google photos.